# VK API video.get ссылка на видео

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, kotlin, api, вконтакте

Можно ли запросом `video.get`, либо каким-то другим, получить прямую ссылку на видео в VK.
От VK API `video.get` приходит ссылка на плеер с этим видео.

```
"player": "https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=92093600&id=456239925&hash=a388b8ddc008e840&__ref=vk.api&api_hash=15992244661d50ee8fe0b7223870_GMYTCMZZGYZA"
```

Comment: Ссылку на видео примерно такого вида: https://vk.com/video?z=video111111111_111111111? Или как выглядит эта прямая ссылка? Плюс, что вы желаете после получения этой ссылки делать с ней?

Comment: @EzikBro нет. Что то типа того vkadre.ru/assets/videos/750c48ae2867-92359355.mp4 . Пишу свое приложение для vk, хочу получать и воспроизводить видео своих друзей в приложении

Comment: Насколько я знаю, VK API дает доступ только к файлам фотографий. Прямого доступа в видеофайлу получить нельзя.

Comment: @EzikBro совершенно верно, именно ссылку на файл. Жаль, что не получится, но в любом случае благодарю за ответ! video.save загружает видео в вк

Comment: Посмотрите еще video.search. Кажется, в поле ["items"]["files"] то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @EzikBro когда проваливаемся в метод search в примере запроса, действительно, есть "files" : "mp4_240" и ссылка. Но стоит нажать кнопку "Выполнить" с теми же самым параметрами, то это поле исчезает